# Is there an algorithm that will correct imprecise bounding boxes?

Tags: python, opencv, image-processing

I am trying to get data from GTA to train my object detection algorithm. However, the ground truth boxes I get are a little off from the exact boundaries. I am trying to get exact coordinates of the bounding box that would be around the gun, but you can see that the game box (in red) is not exact. As I am looking to collect a lot of data, I cannot manually correct them. One approach that seemed promising is to possibly crop the red game box and apply canny edge detection on it, but that would not collect the edges of the object outside of the box. Any automated solutions?

[image]

Comment: Enlarge the box.

Comment: are they AABB or OBB ? do they have any transform matrices along? is the size diference a constant ratio? (like they in different units then rendered). Without any info, input we can only wildly speculate ... why CV and DIP?  do you obtain the BBOX by CV? or from game data?

Comment: Spektre - The bounding boxes are from game data

Comment: add sample (all the stuff that is around ideally with screenshot and view and mesh matrices) you may just wrongly interpret your data, or use wrong multiplication order